# Java Inheritance -> Can't refer to an instance field in constructor error?

Tags: java

I want c to be a random color, so I can spawn many enemies of different color, but not sure how to do it. If I put like Color.cyan in it works fine. But if I want to put a variable in the super() it does not like that. I am new to Java so I am just trying to figure things out. Is this possible without making the variable static?

```
package first.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class MenuEnemy extends Enemy{

    private Random r = new Random();
    private Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));

    public MenuEnemy(float x, float y, Handler handler)
    {
        super(x, y, 16, 16, 2, 8, c, ID.Enemy, handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could provide a [seed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-) to the `Random` object, current timestamp for example

Comment: Okay I can look into that. I am not too familiar with seeds and stuff. I am pretty new to programming

Comment: Move the object construction for `Color` to  `MenuEnemy` constructor.: i.e. `c = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));` inside the constructor

Comment: What is the point on having `protected Color c` in `MenuEnemy`? Was it some attempt to pass color to superclass?

Comment: I did that but it still tells me I cant invoke c to the constructor or something like that. And I meant for it to be private. I just did protected cuz I am new to programming and just tried a bunch of random things to see if something would work. lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the field is not initialized yet as subclass non-static field initialization is executed after super.

There are a few options for you here, 2 possibilities are:

- You could add a static method to get a random color and use that instead of `c` in your constructor.

```java
public static Color getRandomColor() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
}
```

- You could also define the color after you call super, though I'd advise against this as if you use `c` inside the superclass constructor to do something it would fail as we've set it to null, setting it to a random static color may also have unwanted side effects.

```java
    super(..., null, ...);

    Random r = new Random();
    this.c = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
```

---

If you use the first suggestion this would be the end result.

```java
public class Enemy {

    protected float x, y;
    protected int i1, i2, i3, i4;
    protected Color c;

    protected String id;
    protected Handler handler;

    public Enemy(float x, float y, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, Color c, String id, Handler handler) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
        this.i3 = i3;
        this.i4 = i4;
        this.c = c;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public static Color getRandomColor() {
        Random r = new Random(); // TODO possibly reuse a static random somewhere, depends on use-case
        return new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
    }
}

public class MenuEnemy extends Enemy {

    public MenuEnemy(float x, float y, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, 16, 16, 2, 8, Enemy.getRandomColor(), ID.Enemy, handler);
    }

}
```

Comment: "The problem is that when the constructor is called that field does not exist yet" well, field *exists*, but it is not *initialized* yet as subclass non-static field initialization is executed afer `super`.

Comment: How can I define color after I call super? I tried and I get same error. Every enemy has a color, I just made protected to try random stuff to see what could work. I am pretty new to Java and all that so its a bit hard to figure things out so I just mess with some stuff haha. This is the only class that has random color btw, I dont know if that changes things.

Comment: @Pshemo You're absolutely right, I've updated the answer to what you said.

Comment: It says cannot refer to an instance field c while explicitly invoking a constructor

Comment: @AndrewWilken Use first solution from this answer: in `MenuEnemy` create `public static Color getRandomColor() { ... }` method as shown above and call it in `super(..., getRandomColor(), ...)` instead of using `c` (which you probably don't need here so remove that field entirely - its data will be most likely held by field you are trying to initialize in `Enemy` parent class).

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah it worked and thanks for all the help guys. So why does that way work and mine didn't? If its too hard to explain its okay, I just would like to understand it. Obviously the static made it work, but I just wonder why

Comment: @AndrewWilken Sometimes in constructor of subclass we want to use methods from parent class, but those methods often rely on values also declared in parent class. So to safely call such methods state of fields from parent class need to be "set-up" first before any code in subclass constructor will be executed. This is ensured by `super` call which is executed *before any code in subclass constructor, which includes initialization of fields in subclass*. So when you are trying to use `c` in `super(..)` compiler saves you from using its default value (which is `null`).

Comment: Using static methods is safe because they are not independent from instance you are trying to initialize.

Comment: Ah okay. And you said put in MenuEnemy and the guy above put it in Enemy. Both worked. Is one better then the other or doesn't matter?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You can also create additional class (lets call it `class MyUtils{...}`) and add this method there to clean interface of `MenuEnemy` class. But this would require from you to use it with name of that class like `super(..., MyUtils.getRandomColor(), ...);` or to import it statically via `import static your.package.name.MyClass.getRandomColor; ... super(..., getRandomColor(), ..);`.

Answer (score 2):

Can have another constructor.

```
package first.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class MenuEnemy extends Enemy {

    private Random r = new Random();
    protected Color c;

    public MenuEnemy(float x, float y, Handler handler)
    {
        this(x, y, handler, new Color((new Random()).nextInt(255), (new Random()).nextInt(255), (new Random()).nextInt(255)));
    }

    private MenuEnemy(float x, float y, Handler handler, Color c)
    {
        super(x, y, 16, 16, 2, 8, c, ID.Enemy, handler);
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another private constructor can be added, although I don't feel it's required here.
```
private MenuEnemy(float x, float y, Handler handler, Random r)
    {
        this(x, y, handler, new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
        this.r = r;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Builder Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

```java
package first.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

class ID {
    public static final String Enemy = "e";
}

class Handler {
}

class Enemy {

    public Enemy(float x, float y, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, Color c, String id, Handler handler) {
    }

}

public class MenuEnemy extends Enemy {

    private Random r = new Random();
    private Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));

    protected MenuEnemy(Builder builder) {
        super(builder.x, builder.y, 16, 16, 2, 8, builder.c, ID.Enemy, builder.handler);
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private float x;
        private float y;
        private Handler handler;
        private Random r = new Random();
        private Color c;

        public Builder x(float x) {this.x = x; return this;};
        public Builder y(float y) {this.y = y; return this;};
        public Builder handler(Handler handler) {this.handler = handler; return this;};
        public Builder r(Random r) {this.r = r; return this;};
        public Builder c(Color c) {this.c = c; return this;};

        public MenuEnemy build() {
            if(c == null)
                c = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
            return new MenuEnemy(this);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MenuEnemy enemy = new Builder()
                .x(10)
                .y(10)
                .handler(new Handler())
                .r(new Random())
                .build();
        System.out.println(enemy);
    }
}
```